# Changing order of days on Calendar Heatmap in R

Tags: r, plot, calendar, heatmap

I'm using Paul Bleicher's R Calendar Heatmap code (https://github.com/iascchen/VisHealth/blob/master/R/calendarHeat.R)

I have a question relating to changing the format of the dates.

I'd like the heatmap to run from Monday to Sunday, rather than the default Sunday to Saturday. Is there a simple way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

The weekday is defined by %w (0–6, where Sunday is 0). To avoid starting the heatmap on Sundays (as default) we include -1 to this line of code within Paul Bleicher's R function, as follows:

```
caldat$dotw <- as.numeric(format(caldat$date.seq, "%w")) -1
```

Also need to change the labelling:

```
labels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" )
```